# Getting Data from 2 tables not using foreign key Java

Tags: java, sql, for-loop, while-loop, derby

Hi im trying to get data from 2 tables without using a foriegn key. im tryin todo it with a loop, but not having much luck. im trying to use the personid from order2 table to get the the data from personnew table with the same personid .. heres my code any suggestions thanks.. ` ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
            int numberCols = rsmd.getColumnCount();
             ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from ORDER2 ");

```
         int customerid = 0;

         for (int i=1; i<=numberCols; i++)
        {
           if (rs.next()){
            int id = rs.getInt(3);
            System.out.println(id);
            System.out.println("_______");  
            customerid=id;
            List<Integer> x = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            x.add(id);
           }
        }

        while(rs.next())
        {
            int id = rs.getInt(1);
            String restName = rs.getString(2);
            String cityName = rs.getString(3);
            System.out.println(id + "\t\t" + restName + "\t\t" + cityName);
        }

         rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from PERSONNEW WHERE PERSONID=" +customerid );

        for (int i=1; i<=numberCols; i++)
        {

        }

        while(rs.next())
        {
            int id = rs.getInt(1);
            String restName = rs.getString(2);
            String cityName = rs.getString(3);
            System.out.println("PERSON " + id + "\t\t" + restName + "\t\t" + cityName);
        }
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        `
```

Comment: can we see the structure of the two tables in question?

Comment: PERSONNEW TABLE
1  Ola  Hansen
2  Tove  Svendson
3  Kari  Pettersen

and the other table has 3 colums with the person id as the last coulmn orderid,ordero,personid

Comment: I was referring to what columns they had in each table

Comment: ok. sorry.. PERSONNEW has 5 colums personid,firsnatname,lastname street and city inthat order the order2 table has 3 colums orderid,orderno and personid

Comment: Are personID in both tables of the same **data type, precision and scale**? and why are you not wanting to use the foreign key?

Comment: yes they are both tables

Comment: to be honest im new to sql and i couldnt find any tutorials with derby i tred using it but had too many issues , i should really use foriegn key, i got the foriegn key setup in the table, but dont know the query string to use

Comment: its going to look something like select * from personnew inner join order2 on personnew.personID = order2.personid where personnew.personid = " + customerid

Comment: Great thanks how can i get all the results from the table, its showing me only the last one only